# php+jquery+ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo mi siguiente archivo script de ajax
intento pasar los datos a un archivo php pero no me regresa el resultado

```js
<script>
      
      var mensaje = $("#error");
     
      mensaje.hide();
     
        var formData = $("#formlge").serialize();
     
      $("#formlge").on("submit", function(e){
       
        e.preventDefault();
        
      
        
        $.ajax({
          
          type: "POST",
           url: "recursos/validarlogin.php", 
          
          data: formData,
          
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.res);
            console.log( "You clicked a paragraph!" );
                
                if(response.res=="0"){
                  alert("Bienvenido");
                }
                if(response.res=="1"){
                  alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrecto");
                }
             },
          error: function(errMsg) {
              alert("Error\n" + "Datos revizar la conexion " );
          }
          }); 
        });
```

```html
Este es el formulario principal
<form  method="post" id="formlge" >
            <div class="content-formulario-login" action="recursos/validarlogin.php">
                <center>
                  <img src="../imagen/logoItsch.png" class="imgLogin">
                  <p><input type="text" name="usuario" value="" placeholder="Numero de control" class="entrada_login" id ="usuario" required></p><p>
                  <input type="password" name="contrasena" value="" placeholder="Password" class="entrada_login"  required></p>
                 <input  type="submit" id="ingresar" class="btn btn-default" class="entrada_login"  value="Iniciar Secion"/>
            </center>
            </div> 
          </form>
```

**Este es mi php**

```
<?php 
if($_POST){
        include('../../conf/conexion.php');
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
       $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

        $anio=date("Y");

        //Realizo la consulta SQL
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE no_control = '$usuario'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $usuarioSQL=$row['no_control'];
        //echo "string".$usuarioSQL;
        //echo "string".$;
        if(($usuario==$usuarioSQL) && ($contrasena==$anio)){//Valido que la contraseña sea correcta
            $resp=array("res"=>"as");
            }else{$resp=array("res"=>"$usuario.este es el usuario");}//Usuario incorrecto

         echo json_encode($resp);

        //asigno los valores a la variable session
        //imprimo con los case
}else{
    $resp=array("res"=>"No se recibieron datos");
     echo $resp;
}


?>
```

**Al parecer no me esta recibiendo los valores en el php**

Comment: Es simple, debes colocar esta línea var formData = $("#formlge").serialize(); dentro de la función submit, por que ? por que debes capturar los valores del formulario una vez que des click en enviar

Comment: Tienes esto **`var formData = $("#formlge").serialize();` fuera del on.submit, por tanto no tomará los valores del formulario**.  Haz un alert para probar que el submit está funcionando. También ten en cuenta que estás usando una api obsoleta para consultar la base de datos. Me refiero las funciones como `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya lo mencionaron los dos comentarios de arriba el error esta por que tienes

var formData = $("#formlge").serialize();

fuera de la función `submit` Puedes validar y ejecutar un `console.info(formData)` en el "`JavaScript`" para confirmar que si se envíen los datos y a demás ejecutar un `print_r($_POST)` en el php para validar que esta entrando al archivo, recuerda que para ver que responde el archivo php lo puedes hacer desde "`Inspecionar`" la opción "`Network`"